# Are all non-Paving Matroids Linear Matroids?

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, matroids

A matroid is called a *paving* matroid if all circuits of the matroids are of cardinality $k$ or $k+1$, where $k$ is the rank of the matroid. A matroid $(E,I)$ is called a *linear matroid* if there is a field $F$ and a matrix $A$ over $F$ such that $E$ contains the columns of $A$ and $I$ contains all independent sets (as in linear algebra) among subsets of $E$.

**Question: A matroid that is not a paving Matroid is necessarily a linear matroid?**

Answer (score 4):

This question seems to be open, and a positive answer to it implies a long-standing conjecture in the asymptotics of matroids:

**Conjecture 1**: Almost all matroids are paving.

This is Conjecture 1.6 in [On the asymptotic proportion of connected matroids](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0195669811000254) following speculation by Crapo and Rota in the 1970's.

In [Almost All Matroids Are Non-representable](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1605.04288.pdf) it is shown that almost all matroids are non-linear. So if every non-paving matroid is linear, then every non-linear matroid is paving. And since almost all matroids are non-linear, it follows that almost all matroids are paving.